# Can I use acts_as_audited in a rake task?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, acts-as-audited

While `acts_as_audited` works fine with my models, I have a rake task which imports an XML file into my database. All the actions which are performed by this task (mainly create and update) are not picked up by the acts_as_audited. For the record I have added `Audit.as_user(User.current_user) do; ... ; end` in the rake task file *and* to the class which performs the actual task.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I got it and it was no issue with `acts_as_audited`.

Apparently the Rake task which was updating the database was throwing errors. As soon as those corrected and the Task finished, I could see the audits on the tables.

Answer (score 0):

acts_as_audited works with models which is an abstract of database table. It will log the altered table/model name, current column value and modified column value. Rake Tasks are not possible to log.

Comment: Hi Shiva, thanks for the contribution. However, it is indeed possible to log the rake tasks as long as the models that the tasks are making the operations on are being audited.